# Azure - API to fetch current charges and billing cycle

Tags: azure, azure-billing-api

We can view the breakdown of the current charges from the Azure portal and the burn rate. Is there any API (apart from the RateCard and Utilization api) to fetch that? Instead of us calculating the cost, can we just fetch the actual cost per resource using API?

Secondly, is there any API to fetch the billing cycle for the subscription? I think we need Billing cycle to get the cost if there is tiered pricing on the resource and free usage in case we use rate and utilization API.